# Как в python считать csv - файл, если я не знаю разделителя?

Tags: python, csv

Файл представляет собой таблицу 750х3, где во втором и третьем столбце - строки (название и текст некоторой статьи). В строках есть и запятые, и \n, и кавычки. Вот пример отрывка текста (слова просто заменили на синонимичные, новая строка таблицы должна начинаться с числа 261 и заканчиваться числом 262)

> ...112 (для труба связи). "\n',
>    '261,"обитатель москвы соединиться к мировой флешмоб ""в метро без штанов""","обитатель столицы соединиться к международный флешмоб ""в етро без штанов"" (no pants subway ride), который проходит 10 январь метро по весь мир новый пятнадцать год.  в социальный сеть уже появиться один фотография участник акция. по информация , молодая человек спуститься на станция ""тверская"" московский метрополитена, снять брюки, за чё проехать несколько станция по замоскворецкой линия стольный метро.  один от базовый условие флешмоб ""в без штанов"" представать то, чё участники, брать участие в акции, подобающий совершать вид, чё вакуум чудной не происходить. фотография опубликовано марк весёлый (@mark_saaks) янв 10 2016 в 3:24 pst\n',
>    '\n',
>    '""в метро без штанов"" — ежегодная акция, которая проходит 10 январь крупный град мира, в тот число в нью-йорке, париже, лондоне, варшаве и другой.  "\n',
>    '262,русский язык...

`ls.split("','")` спотыкается именно на таких примерах, разделителя лучше я не нашел. Однако `pandas.read_csv(open("C:/test.csv",'r', encoding = 'utf8'))` показывает таблицу нормально, как и [google таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BbGxOXA-gki2C7obcky7wiXQ_h6b2AJky-B_l4K_LOw/edit#gid=661702618).

Как преобразовать этот файл в список, так чтобы он правильно отображался?

Comment: То есть, Вы не хотите использовать готовые парсеры, хотите все ручками?

Comment: @KoVadim а можно поподробнее, я не работал с парсерами

Comment: @KoVadim Всё, разобрался, спасибо